# Trying to run a program in /root/ by other user by adding it to path

Tags: users, environment-variables, path

Specifically, I am using `conda` command part of *Miniconda distribution*. It happens that the installer put files in `/root/miniconda3/`.

The problem is that `/root/miniconda3/bin` is in path, but the command `conda` can only be run by root, not other sudoer.

I tried to set rights to `777` (I know this is bad since it contains compiler and stuff, and it's under root, but this is only for test environment).

Note: I own the root and the sudoer.

Comment: everything under `/root` is by definition only accessible by root by default, and using `sudo` you become "root" (sort of). What is your doubt here?

Comment: I know. But using `sudo conda` returns `sudo: conda: command not found` whil switching to SU mode it does run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo conda` won't necessarily run `/root/.bash_profile` but instead your original account's, unless the `/etc/sudoers` option `always_set_home` is set.

This is by design: it allows multiple administrators on the same system to become root and still maintain their personal shell environment preferences.

Also, because `sudo` always resets the `PATH` environment variable to a standard default value before executing the command as the target user, your `PATH` setting as the original user won't be preserved across `sudo`.

In this case, you'll want the `sudo` command to set `HOME=/root` before executing the `conda` command using the shell, so that the PATH setting  in `/root/.bash_profile` will take effect and `conda` will also find its other configuration files:

- `$HOME/.condarc` file
- `$HOME/.conda/` directory
- `$HOME/.continuum/` directory

To do that, run `sudo -H conda` or `sudo -i conda` instead of just `sudo conda`.